# PoseArray not getting published

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, so I'm trying to find the shortest path from source to destination using dijkstra's algorithm.

In this program, I intend to first store the path in an array from which I retrieve it and publish it as a Pose Array. However, when I run this program I see no PoseArray topics.

I am trying to publish it from inside the dijkstra function.

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>
#include <std_msgs/String.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/Pose.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/PoseArray.h>
#include <nav_msgs/OccupancyGrid.h>
#include <nav_msgs/GetMap.h>
#include <ros/console.h>
#define FMAX 999999999.99


    int rows = 1000, columns = 1000, size = rows * columns;
    bool visited[1000000];
    float distance[1000000];
    int prev[1000000];
    int source = 15100, destination = 990500; // Random source and destination
    .
    .
    .
    
    void dijkstra(const nav_msgs::OccupancyGrid& map)
    {
        prev[source] = 0;
        node first = {source, 0.0}; 
        pq.push(first);
        while(!pq.empty())
        {
            .
                    .
            int rr, cc;
            for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) // to calculate neighbours
            {
                .
                            .
                            .
                .
            }
        }
    
        poseArray.poses = pose_vector;
        ros::NodeHandle n("~");
        ros::Publisher pose_array_pub = n.advertise<geometry_msgs::PoseArray>("/poseArray", 1);
        pose_array_pub.publish(poseArray);
    }
    
    
    
    int main(int argc, char **argv)
    {
        init();
        distance[source] = 0;
        visited[source] = true;
        ros::init(argc, argv, "dijkstra");
        ros::NodeHandle n("~");
        ros::ServiceClient client = n.serviceClient<nav_msgs::GetMap>("/static_map");
        nav_msgs::OccupancyGrid my_map = srv.response.map;
        dijkstra(my_map);
        ros::spin();    
    }
```

EDIT - Deleted parts of my code to make the question more relevant.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/340542/posearray-not-getting-published/) by [Parth2851](https://answers.ros.org/users/48975/parth2851/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2019-12-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We see this:

> ```
> void dijkstra(const nav_msgs::OccupancyGrid& map)
> ```

```
{
  ...
```

> ```
>   ros::NodeHandle n("~");
> ```

```
  ros::Publisher pose_array_pub = n.advertise<geometry_msgs::PoseArray>("/poseArray", 1);
  pose_array_pub.publish(poseArray);
}
```

*Never* create `NodeHandle`s, `ros::Publisher` or `ros::Subscriber`s in the body of callbacks or in short-lived functions.

It will not work.

Also *never* call `publish(..)` immediately after constructing a `ros::Publisher`. There is no time for `Subscriber`s to actually subscribe, so no one receives your message.

Create them in your `main(..)` and pass them to your callback. Or create them as global variables or create a class and store them as members.

Then if you're only publishing the message once, make sure there are subscribers. You can use [ros::Publisher::getNumSubscribers()](http://docs.ros.org/api/roscpp/html/classros_1_1Publisher.html#af5574532bf8a9b35efa3696a035d31fc) for this. But if only publishing once *and* it's important your message always arrives, then I would suggest to use a service instead of a topic.

---

Edit:

> Okay, yes. I made a publisher in mainand then I declared a global poseArray and then published it in a loop something like this -

> ```
> while(ros::ok())
> ```

```
{
  pose_array_pub.publish(pa);
}
```

I would strongly recommend you do not do this. For two reasons (at least):

1. you're not publishing many, many old messages as `pa` is not updated before `publish(..)` is called
2. if this is the exact code you used: you're publishing at the maximum rate at which your PC can publish (which for a typical PC is upwards of 10kHz)

What I was actually suggesting was something like this:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>

...

ros::Publisher pub;   // note: in global scope here

...

void dijkstra(const nav_msgs::OccupancyGrid& map)
{
  ...

  // use variable in global scope
  pub.publish(poseArray);
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "dijkstra");
  ros::NodeHandle n("~");
  ...

  // initialise variable in global scope
  pub = n.advertise<geometry_msgs::PoseArray>("/poseArray", 1);

  ...
  ros::spin();
}
```

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-12-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-12-22**:
PS: yes, this is software, so "never" is never *really* never, but if you're just starting out with all of this, you should really not do this.

**Comment by [Parth2851](https://answers.ros.org/users/48975/parth2851/) on 2019-12-22**:
This worked! thanks!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-12-23**:
For future readers: *what* worked, specifically?

**Comment by [Parth2851](https://answers.ros.org/users/48975/parth2851/) on 2019-12-23**:
Okay, yes. I made a publisher in mainand then I declared a global poseArray and then published it in a loop something like this -

```
while(ros::ok())
        {
            pose_array_pub.publish(pa);
        }
```